# Java - Minimax Algorithm for Numerical Tic Tac Toe Bug

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, minimax

I have an issue with an algorithm I am attempting to implement as an assignment for college. I am making a numerical version of tic tac toe. My lecturer gave our class his version of the Minimax algorithm for the standard game of tic tac toe and we now have to implement this for the numerical tic tac toe. His standard implementation is as follows:

```
public class MinimaxPlayer extends BasePlayer {

private Random randomGenerator;

public MinimaxPlayer(Board board, int symbol) {
    super(board, symbol);
    name = "MinimaxPlayer";

    skill = 5;  // skill is measure of search depth

    randomGenerator = new Random();
}

@Override
public int move () {
    return (int) minimax(mySymbol, opponentSymbol, 0);
}

private float minimax(int p_mySymbol, int p_opponentSymbol, int depth) {

    final float WIN_SCORE = 100;        
    final float DRAW_SCORE = 0;

    float score;
    float maxScore = -10000;
    int maxPos = -1;

    // for each board position
    for (int r=0; r<3; ++r) {
        for (int c=0; c<3; ++c) {

            // skip over used positions
            if (board.cells[r][c]!=board.EMPTY) continue;

            String indent = new String(new char[depth]).replace("\0", "  ");
            //Gdx.app.log(indent, "search ("+r+","+c+")");

            // place move 
            board.cells[r][c] = p_mySymbol;

            // evaluate board (recursively)
            if (board.hasWon(p_mySymbol, r, c)) {
                score = WIN_SCORE;
            } else if (board.isDraw()) {
                score = DRAW_SCORE;
            } else {
                if (depth<skill) {
                    score = -minimax(p_opponentSymbol, p_mySymbol, depth+1);
                } else {
                    score = 0;
                }
            }

            // update ranking

            if (Math.abs(score-maxScore)<1.0E-5 && randomGenerator.nextDouble()<0.1) {
                maxScore = score;
                maxPos = 3*r+c;

            } else if (score>maxScore) {    // clear 
                maxScore = score;
                maxPos = 3*r+c;
            } 

            //Gdx.app.log(indent, "Score "+score);

            // undo move 
            board.cells[r][c] = board.EMPTY;

        }
    }

    // on uppermost call return move not score
    return (depth==0? maxPos : maxScore);

};
```

}

I am now attempting to adapt this code to suit my numerical tic tac toe game. So far I have this:

```
public class MinimaxPlayer extends BasePlayer {

private Random randomGenerator;
//change constructor to take skill levels for depth search.
public MinimaxPlayer(Board board, Symbol symbol,int depth) {
    super(board, symbol);
    name = "MinimaxPlayer";

    // skill is measure of search depth
    skill = depth;

    randomGenerator = new Random();
}

@Override
public int move () {
    return  (int) minimax(board.currentPlayer.numbers, board.currentPlayer.opponent.numbers, 0);
}

private float minimax(List<Integer> myNumbers, List<Integer> opponentNumbers, int depth) {

    final float WIN_SCORE = 100;        
    final float DRAW_SCORE = 0;

    float score;
    float maxScore = -10000;
    int maxPos = -1;

    // for each board position
    for (int r=0; r<3; ++r) {
        for (int c=0; c<3; ++c) {
            for(Integer number : myNumbers){
                // skip over used positions
                if (board.cells[r][c]!=board.EMPTY) continue;

                // place move 
                board.cells[r][c] = number;
                System.out.println("Number placed :" + number);


                // evaluate board (recursively)
                if (board.hasWon(number, r, c)) {
                    score = WIN_SCORE;
                    System.out.println("This move has won with score: "+ score);
                } else if (board.isDraw()) {
                    score = DRAW_SCORE;
                    System.out.println("this move is a draw and score is: " + score);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Depth is now: " + depth);
                    if (depth<skill) {
                        score = -minimax(opponentNumbers, myNumbers, depth+1);
                    } else {
                        score = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Made it to update rankings");
                // update ranking
                if (Math.abs(score-maxScore)<1.0E-5 && randomGenerator.nextDouble()<0.1) {
                    currentNumber = number;
                    maxScore = score;
                    maxPos = 3*r+c;

                } else if (score>maxScore) {    // clear 
                    currentNumber = number;
                    maxScore = score;
                    maxPos = 3*r+c;
                } 

                //Gdx.app.log(indent, "Score "+score);
                System.out.println("Undone move");
                // undo move 
                board.cells[r][c] = board.EMPTY;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Depth:" + depth);
    System.out.println("MaxScore:" + maxScore);
    System.out.println("MaxPosition: "+ maxPos);
    // on uppermost call return move not score
    return (depth==0 ? maxPos : maxScore);

};
```

The code is pretty straight forward, I substitute the algorithms arguments for my remaining numbers I can play and my opponents numbers they can play and go about recursively trying to get the best move for the player by trying each number in each board position and giving it a score. The same applies for the opponent. This code however ends in an infinite loop which I am finding hard to debug because I am new to Libgdx,hence the prints to the console. I think the problem is to do with the base case needing to change for the recursive function but I am not too sure, I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction as to how I could cycle through a players numbers and give them the best position and where I have wrote 'currentNumber = number' be aware that each player has a current number which is set before playing the number on the board because the game features drag and drop. So somewhere within the algorithm I need to set the players number to the best number to play. Some guidelines and advice on how to fix the infinite loop would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where do you define EMPTY in if (board.cells[r][c]!=board.EMPTY) continue;?

Comment: @Floam EMPTY is defined within the board class that is given to the constructor of the MinimaxPlayer. EMPTY is just a final int of value 0. This represents an empty space on the board,so if the space isn't empty then there is no point in checking it so we 'continue' and skip that space.

Comment: Can you post the contents of BasePlayer. I'm wondering if it has something to do with:

if (depth<skill) {
                        score = -minimax(opponentNumbers, myNumbers, depth+1);
                    } 


In MinimaxPlayer, you set the skill = depth. BasePlayer will help me recognize how they came to existence.